# JBoss Fuse camel dsl using camel-netty4-http - how to I obtain the REST return code in order to log it?

Tags: java-8, apache-camel, jbossfuse

***QUESTION:***

*I'm using JBoss Fuse and camel-netty4-http to post to a REST service.

-How would I obtain the REST return code - aka, "status code" - (in order to log it)?*

***sample code:***

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

... 

from("wmq:queue:mylocalqueue")
    .log("inMessage=" + (null==body()?"":body().toString()))
    .to("seda:node1?concurrentConsumers=20");

from("seda:node1")
    .streamCaching()
    .threads(20)
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.POST))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
    .toD("netty4-http:http://localhost:7001/MyService/myServiceThing?textline\\=true")
    .log("the http return/status code is [what?]...";  <=== need response/http code!!!    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response code should be in your `Exchange` header. You could use a simple expression to extract it. Like this:

```
from("direct:start")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.POST))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
    .to("netty4-http:http://localhost:8080")
    .log("The response code is: ${header["+Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE+"]}");
```

Comment: is it possible to access the return code inside an "onException" handler, as well?: 
onException(Exception.class).log(${header["+Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE+"]}"                      ...I seem to be having difficulty obtaining it

Comment: I think it is. The message is propagated in the exception. In theory you have the same data.